# create resource name based on terraform.workspace

Tags: terraform

I want to have different s3 names based on different environments using terraform.

If I define the name in terraform.tfvar, it won't work:

```
s3_bucket_name          = "tf-${terraform.workspace}"
```

If I hardcode s3 bucket name in s3.tf, it works:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
   bucket        = "tf-${terraform.workspace}"
   ....
}
```

how to define the workspace related name from terraform.tfvar? I do not want to hard code it in tf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are static, literal inputs to your configuration that come from either the command line or from `tfvars` files. It is not possible to use interpolations here, since the variable values are processed before interpolation begins in order to make them available to other expressions.

---

If the goal is to define the S3 bucket name in one place and re-use it several times in the same configuration, the *[Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html)* feature can do this if you are using Terraform v0.10.4 or newer. You can declare the named value in one of your `.tf` files:

```
locals {
  s3_bucket_name = "tf-${terraform.workspace}"
}
```

You can then interpolate this value in various places in your configuration using the name `local.s3_bucket_name`, like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "${local.s3_bucket_name}"
  ...
}
```

Local values are conceptually similar to [module outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) but they are exposed within the same module they are defined in, rather than passing a value up to the parent module.

---

If the goal is to allow this generated default name to be overriden optionally by a variable, then that can be achieved with some conditional logic:

```
variable "override_s3_bucket_name" {
  default = ""
}

locals {
  s3_bucket_name = "${var.override_s3_bucket_name != "" ? var.override_s3_bucket_name : "tf-${terraform.workspace}"}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "${local.s3_bucket_name}"
  ...
}
```

The above will generate a default name based on the selected workspace if `override_s3_bucket_name` is not set, but if that variable is set then its value will be used instead.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I will use your local variable solutions!